# Reg Alert interface in Webdriver Selenium

Tags: selenium, webdriver

Alert interface have no implementing classes. And I also have seen these lines of code in many tutorials

```
Alert al=driver.switchTo().alert();

al.accept();
```

`accept()` is a  method in Alert, then how we can use `accept()` method?

I have just started learning **Selenium** and it is confusing me how can we call interface methods directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its simple that a method `alert()` is returning object of the class where `Alert` interface is implemented. `WeDriver` interface contains method `switchTo()` having return type as interface containing method `alert()` having return type as `Alert` interface. Now, these methods are implemented inside `RemoteWebDriver` class having number of nested classes. Hence, when you write above code to handle alert you are actually referring to `RemoteWebDriver` nested class object. see simple example code below to understand this.

```
interface Driver{
    Switch switchTo();
    interface Switch{
        Alert alert();
    }
}

interface Alert {
 void accept();
}

class RemoteDriver implements Driver{
    public Switch switchTo()
    {
       return new SwitchTo();
    }
    class SwitchTo implements Switch 
    {
        public Alert alert()
        {
           return new AlertHandler();
        }
    }
    class AlertHandler implements Alert{
       public void accept()
       {
          //code to accept alert.
       }
    }
}
```

}